# All cassandra's commit log functions and behaviour during flush

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, nodetool

I'm using cassandra `2.2.1` and noticed that after `nodetool flush` *commitlog* files are not deleted (actually, may be some are, I didn't see, but *commitlog* dir is not empty).

1. What is happening during `nodetool flush` or just regular *flush*? Are all *commitlog* files supposed to be deleted during this process?
2. Is data from *commitlog* used only during node repair or also during *flush*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Commitlog files are pre-allocated and reused rather than deleted.  This improves performance.  See more information [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-3411).

The commitlog is used if a node goes down before a memtable has been flushed to an SSTable.  This is done by replaying the commitlog to recreate the memtable.  When you do a flush, then the space in the commitlog can be reclaimed and reused.

Comment: so, just to be sure, during regular flush commitlog is not used at all, and exists **only** for critical situations, right?

Comment: Correct.  If data is successfully flushed then the information in the commitlog corresponding to the flush is simply discarded.